# Unit Test a submodule static function in iOS? (Swift 4 - Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have 4 submodules in my iOS project (Project A).

In one submodule (X Submodule) I have a class with a static function that get as input an Object defined in another submodule (Y submodule) and return a String.

How and where do I write a unit test for this static function logic? Do I write the logic in one of the App projects (A, B, C iOS Projects) that re-use those submodules (X, Y submodules)?

If you have any suggestion it will be highly appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just as you've created multiple frameworks for your app, you can create multiple test targets. It probably makes sense to create a test target in your X subproject that validates the X submodule.